# You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP in easyphp dev server 17

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, easyphp

I have a problem when i want to install new project cakephp 3.5

first i have easyphp dev server 17

and in cmd when i want to create a new project i have this error

[image]

can you help me ??

Comment: Your problem is that you need to enable the php-intl extension in the easyphp-devserver system. Cakephp 3.5 requires this extension to be present. Alternatively, try to get your Cakephp up and running in xampp or another windows php webserver package.

Comment: can you help me how can i enable the php-intl extension  in the easyphp-devserver system ??

Comment: edit you php.ini file,   search for php_intl the remove the symbol(;) from the starting of that line, then restart your server will work :)